# java.security.SignatureSpi usage

Tags: java, security, digital-signature

I extended my class by SignatureSpi and I want to sign text file using this class. However, there is one problem, I don't know how to use this class. All methods are protected. Do you have any examples of usages? I was trying to find something on google but without results. ;/

Comment: `SignatureSpi` is a Service Provider Interface class. If you are interested in SPI implementation you might want to read [How to Implement a Provider in the Java Cryptography Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you cannot just extend the `Signature` class. You need to create a Java security provider, which then registers the underlying `SignatureSpi` class. Then, when the user uses one of the `Signature.getInstance()`, the `SignatureSpi` within your provider *could* be used as underlying implementation. Since 1.5, the `Signature.init()` method will also be of importance because of the possibility to use *delayed provider selection* based on the given key.

So there are two ways of using your own algorithm. One is to create your own interface and use that. This is for example performed by the Bouncy Castle light API. The other method is to create your own provider, but within the Oracle runtimes, that provider **needs to be signed** by a certificate/key pair of which the certificate has been signed by Oracle. The advantage of the latter is that the algorithm may also be used by libraries that use the `Signature` class, such as the TLS implementation and XML digital signature libraries provided by Oracle.

mkl nicely provided the link to more information: [How to Implement a Provider in the Java Cryptography Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html)